# I'm getting a error in Google App Engine to do with import sqlite3? Can somebody help me please?

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, import, sqlite, importerror

The error I getting is:

```
raise ImportError('No module named %s' % fullname)
```

ImportError: No module named _sqlite3

```
from _sqlite3 import *

from dbapi2 import *

import sqlite3
```

It has something to do with:

```
import sqlite3
```

Can anyone help me please? I'm using Google App Engine for Python on a Windows 7 machine just in case that has something to do with it.

The help would be much appreciate.

Thanks

Comment: The udacity course says it works with GAE, so something should work. Two things to check 1) Where is the "import sqlite" statement that is failing - your code or library code? 2) Can you run the python shell and just type "import sqlite", to check that your system works OK.

Answer (score 1):

Not really sure about your case, but it helped me a couple of times. You should add _sqlite3 to _WHITE_LIST_C_MODULES to python sandbox module here:

```
[path_to_google_app_engine]/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/sandbox.py
```

somehow like this:

```
_WHITE_LIST_C_MODULES = [
    'array',
    '_ast',
    ...
    '_sqlite3'
]
```

Comment: So where do I type: [path_to_google_app_engine]/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/sandbox.py in and the rest of the code???

Comment: You should find file sandbox.py in the directory with Google App Engine SDK by given path (since you're using Windows it should be C:/Program Files/Google/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/sandbox.py). Then open it in text editor, locate definition of  _WHITE_LIST_C_MODULES list (at the bottom) and append '_sqlite3' to it.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am aware, Google App Engine does not support sqlite. It has its own database system, that uses a vaguely SQL like language call GQL.

To prevent you accidently using the wrong database, the developement environment has intercepted your import of sqlite, and has raised an error.

Comment: Not true. We support sqlite3 as an alternate development-mode datastore.

Comment: Is this using it as a backend to the GAE datastore, or for the application accessing SQLITE directly? The second is what I meant, and is what you have re-iterated in your answer.

Comment: So how can I use sqlite3 because I'm following the Udacity CS253: WEB APPLICATION ENGINEERING course and the lecturer there uses sqlite3 fine with no errors. I'm stuck on lesson 14 of Unit 3 Databases in Python.

Comment: The course material isn't visible to me. If they're using app engine, they might be using the --use_sqlite option for the dev_appserver, but that says to use sqlite for the datastore simulation (instead of flat files).

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly use sqlite3 from our dev_appserver unless you're willing to modify our source. The reason is that dev_appserver is supposed to give you a development-time experience that simulates what's available (and not avilable) when you upload code to appsot.com. sqlite3 won't be available then.